# Как автоматически на linux передавать логин пароль wifi?

Tags: linux, wifi

Требуется, чтобы Raspberry Pi автоматически подключался к Wi-fi.

Wi-fi-точка настроена так, что при подключении к ней автоматически открывается браузер, где нужно ввести логин и пароль и поставить галочку (соглашение с правилами).

К wi-fi обычно подключаюсь с помощью wicd.

Как передавать логин и пароль автоматически, например при помощи curl (-F)?

Comment: я бы делал так. Написал скрипт, который умеет с помощью curl сделать нужные запросы и поставил бы upstart (или systemd, что там у Вас) на запуск после поднятия сети. Но и сам wicd умеет запускать скрипты. так даже правильнее будет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если вы используете программу *wicd*, то, согласно [`man wicd`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/wicd), для выполнения каких-либо действий после установки соединения [можно использовать](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/34439/110559), например, скрипт оболочки, поместив его в каталог `/etc/wicd/scripts/postconnect/`

для привязки к нужному интерфейсу в этом скрипте можно использовать [переданные скрипту параметры](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/wicd#Scripts):

```
$1 - the connection type (wireless/wired).
$2 - the ESSID (network name).
$3 - the BSSID (gateway MAC).
```

[примерно так](http://kissmyarch.blogspot.ru/2011/09/wicd-network-independent.html):

```
if [ "$1" == "wireless" -a "$2" == "имя-точки-доступа" ]; then
  curl ...
fi
```

а уж какие параметры передать программе *curl* (*wget* и т.п.), чтобы она «залогинилась» на страничке провайдера, целиком и полностью зависит от содержимого этой странички.